# Adding dependency to class only because another [child] dependency needs it

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design

I am noticing occasions where I need to add dependencies to parent classes, and their parents and so on, only because a child class needs it. Is this a code smell? Is it reasonable for a parent class to need information only because a child class needs it?

In particular in our [slightly anemic] flavor of DDD this seems to occur with Application Services (Domain boundary) needing information from our application layer to pass on to Domain Services. It is quite painful to add dependencies to app services calling a particular domain service and all of the associated tests when a domain service needs a new dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a smell. If your child class needs some dependency, then inject dependency directly into child class. And let parent class know (i.e. be dependent) only about child.

*BTW* Are you sure that in your case *dependency* is passed to domain service? *Dependency* is a specific service that is required by dependent object to fulfill its function. It looks like in your case simple data is passed to domain service.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is a design smell, your types should take only the minimum dependencies they need. If they require a service which requires other dependencies, then those dependencies should be injected to the service, not the type that uses the service.

If you are using an IoC container, it will take care of these dependency chains for you. If you need to instantiate new instances of a type at runtime, then you should inject factory types.